# Throwing exception in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

In apache camel is there a difference if I just :

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

or :

```
exchnage.setException(new RuntimeException())
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both of them , setException method works for this two case, they give the same result